# Showing error before executing the code in selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The Following code show Error  , the error  it is  showing is - **"Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebElement"**.
    I am using
    Eclipse version Mar(4.5.0)
    Firefox version -49.0.2
    selenium -3.0.1
    geckodriver-0.11.1
    jdk-8u111

```
package WebdriverPart1;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
public class MouseOverA17 {
public static void main(String[]args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:/Programs/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64/geckodriver.exe");   
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.carmax.com/");
Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
WebElement menuElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sell Your Car")).click();
builder.moveToElement(menuElement).build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Used Cars for Sale")).click();
driver.close();
}
}
```

This code
    **driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sell Your Car")).click();**
 showing the error .I don't know where i am getting wrong, please help.

Answer (score 1):

`click()` method returns `void` but you try to assign it to `WebElement`. You need to split it to two

```
WebElement menuElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sell Your Car"));
menuElement.click();
```